# JavaScript regular expression to replace a sequence of chars

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all spaces in the beginning and the end of a string with a underscore in this specific situation:

```
var a = '   ## ## #  ';
console.log(myReplace(a)); // prints ___## ## #__
```

i.e.: all the spaces in the beginning of the string before the first # and all the spaces after the last #, everything else (including spaces in the middle of the string) remains untouched.

My initial thinking was to use two Reg Exp, one for each part of the problem.

However, I couldn't get the first one and I'm not sure if it's even possible to do what I want using JS regexp.

```
str.replace(/^\ /g, '_'); // replaces only the first space
str.replace(/^\ +/, '_') //  replaces all the correct spaces with only one underscore
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a callback function:

```
var newStr = str.replace(/(^( +)|( +)$)/g, function(space) { 
                             return space.replace(/\s/g,"_");
                           }
                         );
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit! My JS is rusty, I remembered about callbacks in JS regexps, but since the Mozilla docs didn't mention it, I thought I was wrong.

Comment: @Tiago [they do here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: @m.buettner: Oh, I thought [this was the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) but it's only the guide. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var result = str.replace(/^ +| +$/g,
             function (match) { return new Array(match.length+1).join('_'); });
```

Comment: Thanks Casimir! I'm choosing Rohit's answer as correct because he answered first and his solution works as expected. I'm likely to use your way, though, because it's more elegant and it's something I never used before.

Comment: "something I never used before": me too.

Answer (score 2):

This one is tough in JavaScript. With ECMAScript 6, you could use `/[ ]/y` which would require the matches to be adjacent, so you could match spaces one-by-one but make sure that you don't go past the first non-space. For the end of the string you can (in any case) use `/[ ](?=[ ]*$)/`.

For ECMAScript 5 (which is probably more relevant to you), the easiest thing would be to use a replacement callback:

```
str = str.replace(
    /^[ ]+|[ ]+$/g,
    function(match) {
        return new Array(match.length + 1).join("_");
    }
);
```

This will programmatically read the number of spaces and write back just as many underscores.

Comment: Thanks m.buettner. You're right, ECMAScript 5 is more relevant, but thanks for providing more info to the subject. I surely didn't know about this new feature of ECMAScript 6. As I commented in Casimir's answer, I'm choosing Rohit's answer as correct because he answered first.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted this answer, because it evidently doesn't answer the question for JavaScript. I'm undeleting it so future searchers can find a regexy way to get whitespace at the ends of strings.

**this doesn't correctly answer your question, but might be useful for others**

This regex will match all whitespace at the beginning and end of your string:

```
^(\s*).*?(\s*)$
```

Just replace the capturing groups with underscores!