# Match string words with special chars like $ or ! and replace them

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to process on input string as following -

```js
// Input string - 
'My pen cost is !!penCost!! manufactured in $$penYear$$ with colors !!penColor1!! and $$penColor1$$'
// Processed string
'My pen cost is <penCost> manufactured in <penYear> with colors <penColor1> and <penColor1>'
```

Although, I have managed to do it using loop, but interested in knowing a RegEx approach.
This is the current state of my experiment(in non-working condition) -

```js
const regex = /\b(\w*([a-zA-Z])|([\!]{2}[a-zA-Z][\!]{2})\w*)\b/g;
// str is holding the input string
str.replace(regex, (match) => {
  return `<${match.substring(2, match.length - 2)}>`;
});
```

I got stuck on RegEx to properly match words having value like "$$[a-zA-Z0-9]$$" or "!![a-zA-Z0-9]!!".

My approach is a combination of [word match](https://www.regextester.com/95367) and [match replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494868/javascript-regular-expression-to-replace-a-sequence-of-chars#18494952).

Comment: `[\!{2}]` will match `!` or `{` or `2` or `}`, and not `!` two times. Most symbols loose special meaning within a character class (within `[` and `]`),

Comment: You are correct. I was experiment with different variations of mentioned RegEx. And entered a wrong one in the question :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use:

```
str = str.replace(/(!!|\$\$)([\w-]+)\1/g, '<$2>');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6zuGLR/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(!!|\$\$)` Match `!!` or `$$` and capture in group #1
- `([\w-]+)` Match 1+ word or hyphen characters and capture in group #2
- `\1`: Make sure string ends with same starting delimiters as in group #1
- **Replacement** is `<$2>` to wrap string in group #2 in `<` and `>`

**Code:**

```js
const str = 'My pen cost is !!penCost!! manufactured in $$penYear$$ with colors !!penColor1!! and $$penColor1$$';

const res = str.replace(/(!!|\$\$)([\w-]+)\1/g, '<$2>');

console.log(res);
//=> My pen cost is <penCost> manufactured in <penYear> with colors <penColor1> and <penColor1>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great answer. I didn't know that we can check for matches within RegEx like `\1`. That is why I was wondering why the 2nd param is `'<$2>'` instead of `'<$1>'`.

Comment: Hello anubhava sir, could you please vote to re-open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65425958/redirect-multiple-urls-through-htaccess question, thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

code

```
[!,$]{2}[A-Za-z0-9]+[!,$]{2}
```

Comment: There is no need for `,` - it just instructs the regex to look for that character, doesn't separate different entries in a character class

Comment: Like the other answer, this will also match `!!penCost$$`.

Comment: It matches `$!blah!$`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```js
// Input string - 
const str = 'My pen cost is !!penCost!! manufactured in $$penYear$$ with colors !!penColor1!! and $$penColor1$$'
const result = str.replace(/[!$]{2}(\S+)[!$]{2}/g,"<$1>")
console.log(result)

// Processed result
// My pen cost is <penCost> manufactured in <penYear> with colors <penColor1> and <penColor1>
```

Comment: This will also match `!!penCost$$`

Comment: Thant you. Please don't mind but I am going to accept @林添耀 answer as he/she answered it 1st.

Comment: It matches `$!blah!$`