# redirect multiple URLs through .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have many pages with similar urls like:

```
https://example.com/mainpage/1
https://example.com/mainpage/2
https://example.com/mainpage/3
.
..
https://example.com/mainpage/100
```

I want to redirect them using `.htaccess` to new individual pages. Like:

- `https://example.com/mainpage/1` should redirect to `https://example.com/mainpage-1`
- `https://example.com/mainpage/2` should redirect to `https://example.com/mainpage-2`
- `https://example.com/mainpage/3` should redirect to `https://example.com/mainpage-3`

and so on.

since there are many pages of very similar URLs, I want to know if a single code of each kind can work.

P.S. : I have little knowledge of coding. Need help for my personal blog

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your .htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: I dont have coding skills.
read on google how to do redirect thru .htaccess.
As the number of pages are too high just wanted to know can I do it using a single line code.

Comment: @RakeshVishwakarma If you are using WordPress then presumably you already have an `.htaccess` file? The order of directives is important and knowing what directives you have already can avoid conflicts.

Comment: Why was this question closed?! It's not a "general computing hardware and software" question. It's a question about HTTP redirection, related to the web application logic - like the 1000's of other related questions on SO!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Please clear your browser cache before you test your URLs. 1st one is specific to shown samples, keeping mainpage string into 1st backreference and rest digits after `/` in 2nd backreference which we are using them while redirecting on its right side part.

***Specific to samples:***

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(mainpage)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1-$2 [R=302,NC,L]
```

***Generic one:***

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1-$2 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I tred this code:
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(rc-practice-with-explanation)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1-$2 [NC,L]
its not working

the currect url is 
https://bodheeprep.com/rc-practice-with-explanation/3
want to redirect to
https://bodheeprep.com/rc-practice-with-explanation-3

Even tried this :
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^rc-practice-with-explanation/([0-9]+)/?$ $1-$2 [NC,L]
still not workign

Comment: @RakeshVishwakarma, These Rules are tested and they worked fine for me, do you have any other rules in your htaccess file?

Comment: It looks like the OP is wanting to externally 3xx "redirect" the user, rather than internally "rewrite" the request (which won't actually work if they are using WordPress). And importantly, these directives will need to go _before_ the existing WordPress directives (front-controller) in `.htaccess`.

Comment: Minor point, the `NC` is not required when using the `\w` regex shorthand character class since this naturally includes both upper and lowercase letters already.

Comment: @MrWhite, thank you sir for letting this know. I appreciate you it guidance here. You are truly a champ of rules. Cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 should I copy paste the content of .htaccess here for your reference.
Hope this will not expose me with any security issue

Comment: @RakeshVishwakarma, no its always advised to show samples only not exact values for any code/rules etc, put values alike to actual NOT actual ones, cheers.

Comment: @RakeshVishwakarma, you could look into Mr.White's comments that could give you some thoughts too, let us know on his questions, thank you.

Comment: Ok.
The website runs on wordpress 5.6 version. 
What rule @MrWhite talking about? 
Can you help me to figureout the same

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Is there any other way other than .htaccess to achieve the goal?

Comment: @RakeshVishwakarma, see Mr.White's comments in question section `If you are using WordPress then presumably you already have an .htaccess file? The order of directives is important and knowing what directives you have already can avoid conflicts.` you could answer him to it.

Comment: somewhere in the file the following lines are written
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

@MrWhite are you refering to this?

Comment: @RakeshVishwakarma The directives above should go _before_ the `# BEGIN WordPress` section. It also looks like you want to "redirect" the user (as opposed to "rewrite"), so you'll need to add the `R` (or `R=302`) flag to the `RewriteRule` directive. eg. `RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /$1-$2 [R=302,L]` - note also the slash prefix on the _substitution_ string (although that may not be strictly necessary since WordPress usually defines `RewriteBase /`. However, explicitly including the slash prefix on an external redirect is recommended).

Comment: Fantastic !!
IT WORKED. 
Many thanks  @MrWhite and Ravinder Singh

Comment: @RakeshVishwakarma, Thanks to Mr.white too. cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: You need to fix the answer by including `R=302` as suggested by MrWhite

Comment: @anubhava, Thank you anubhava sir for reminding, I have added it now in answer.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 please help me how to adjust the above coding if the "mainpage" portion is different but the suffix (i.e. the number is same. 
For example, 
https://example.com/mainpage/1 should redirect to https://example.com/NEWPAGE-1

Comment: @RakeshVishwakarma, sure, you could open a new question for same and let me know the link I could answer it there, thank you.